# Dispatch an "oninput" event with a custom { target : { value } } data

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dom-events

I'm trying to use [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) on an `<input>` element in a unit test to trigger its "oninput" handler with a custom `{target: {value: "data"}}`

[This guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) only tells you how to trigger a [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent). But I don't think that'll work as it only lets you specify a "details" property. I'm actually trying to trigger it with something like `{target: {value: "data"}}`

There's also [InputEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent/InputEvent) but it too seems to take the same "details" property only.

Here's my `<input>`:

```
<input
   oninput={handleOnInput} // jsx
>
...
function handleOnInput(e){
    const data = e.target.value; // << needs to be mocked
}
```

And this is my test code:

```
getThatInputEl().dispatchEvent(what can trigger "input" with {target: {value: "data"}} ?)
```

Is there a way you can dispatch an "input" event with a custom `{target: value: "data"}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you dispatch `input` event on actual `input` element `e.target` is always set to the element, you can't override it - you can only pass object with additional data. To solve your problem you just have to set value of input before dispatching event or you can test event handler itself